# Calling isKindOfClass throws an error in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to implement [subscripting](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/) in my custom class and thus implemented the following methods:

```objectivec
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key;
```

But I have a strange issue, because I've never met it before: `[(id)obj isKindOfClass:]` throws an ARC Semantic Issue:

```
No known instance method for selector 'isKindOfClass:'
```

As far as I remember, I didn't have any problems with `id` before... Is it a bug with Xcode (I'm using the Xcode 5 Developer Preview 2), or  have I forgotten something important?

```objectivec
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key {
    if(![key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { // error
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I could reproduce the issue with Xcode 4.6.3, so this is not some beta software bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isKindOfClass:` is a method of the `NSObject` **protocol**, so you can either
declare `key` as conforming to the protocol

```
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying, NSObject> )key { ...
```

or require `key` to be derived from `NSObject` (which conforms to that protocol):

```
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSObject <NSCopying> *)key { ...
```

Comment: Leaving the protocol conformation declaration off makes the error go away also. Isn't it weird that declaring an object as `id` will not trigger any errors, but declaring it as `id <NSCopying>` will if it's sent a message not in the `NSCopying` protocol? It's still an "object of any type" and saying that it conforms to `NSCopying` doesn't mean that it doesn't conform anything else...

Comment: @Scott: I don't have a reference at hand, but as far as I remember, only the plain `id` is a "wildcard" that can receive any messages.

Comment: @scott - In the "specification" (a generous term) for Obj-C Apple writes that `id <protocol>` "groups all objects that conform to the protocol into *a type*" (emphasis added). From this you get the meaning you are seeing here "an object which conforms to a protocol", so just as you can't send any message to an object declared as, say, `NSArray *`, you can't send any message to something conforming to a protocol. It is only the unadorned `id` which allows any method the compiler has knowledge of.

Comment: Both thanks! @CRD: I'd like to read more about that, do you have a link to that specification?

Comment: @scott - its "The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language". It is, or was, in the Xcode documentation but you can just Google it and pick a link. But remember Objective-C is very much defined by its compilers :-(

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If I understand correctly: if there was no protocol specified (i.e. `- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key`, compiler would pretend that it conforms to `NSObject`? And specifying a protocol that does not conform to `NSObject` (such as `NSCopying`) means that the object conforms **only to this protocol and no else**? PS: I though every protocol conforms to `NSObject` (e.g. `UIAlertViewDelegate`), but checking the `NSObject.h` disappointed me. :(

Comment: @akashivskyy: The first part is almost correct. For an object declared as `id`, the compiler assumes that you can send *any message* to it. The second part about `id <protocol>` is correct.